# AngularJs - get value from ng-model (ng-option)

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a dependency dropdown from JSON(country, city). Based on country selection city will populate in second dropdown. If I get the value of country it return object with city list.

please wait to get country dropdown value from github raw.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('dropdown', function($scope, $http){
 $scope.istrue = true;
 $scope.userInfo = [];

 $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json').then(function(response){
  $scope.countriesToCities = response.data;
  //console.log($scope.countriesToCities)
 },function(response){
  console.log(response.status);
 });
 
 $scope.populateCities = function() {
  $scope.istrue = false;
  //console.log($scope);
  $scope.cityArray = $scope.users.country;
 }
 
 $scope.selectedCity = function(){
  console.log($scope.city)
 }
 
 $scope.pushInArray = function() {
  var user = angular.copy($scope.users);
  $scope.userInfo.push(user);
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dropdown">
 <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="users.name" placeholder="Name">
 <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="users.email" placeholder="Email">
 <input type="text" name="phoneNo" ng-model="users.phoneNo" placeholder="phone Number">
 <select ng-model="users.country" ng-change='populateCities()' ng-options="x for (x, y) in countriesToCities"></select>
 <select ng-hide="istrue" ng-model="users.city" ng-change='selectedCity()' ng-options="x for x in cityArray"></select>
 <button ng-click="pushInArray()">Add</button>
 <pre>{{userInfo}}</pre>
</div>
```

How to get the value of country?

Comment: try this `ng-options="country.countryId as  country.countryName  for country in countriesToCities"`. of course i don't konw what is keys of counrty object.

Comment: here country name as key

Comment: do you want to put `countryName` in `users.country` or `countryId` in `users.country`?

Comment: countryName in users.country

Comment: so use this `ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in countriesToCities"`

Comment: But I don't have name index in object

Comment: JSON like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working snippet with modified `$scope.populateCities()`, `$scope.user = {}` object and ng-options to select correct country.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('dropdown', function($scope, $http){
$scope.istrue = true;
$scope.userInfo = [];
$scope.user = {};

$http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json').then(function(response){
 $scope.countriesToCities = response.data;
 //console.log($scope.countriesToCities)
},function(response){
 console.log(response.status);
});

$scope.populateCities = function() {
  $scope.istrue = false;
  angular.forEach($scope.countriesToCities, function(values, key) {
      if($scope.user.country == key) {
    $scope.cityArray = values;
      }
  });
}

$scope.pushInArray = function() {
  var user = angular.copy($scope.user);
  $scope.userInfo.push(user);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dropdown">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="users.name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="text" name="phoneNo" ng-model="user.phoneNo" placeholder="phone Number">
  <select ng-model="user.country" ng-change='populateCities()' ng-options="country as country for (country, cities) in countriesToCities"></select>
  <select ng-hide="istrue" ng-model="user.city" ng-change='selectedCity()' ng-options="x for x in cityArray"></select>
  <button ng-click="pushInArray()">Add</button>
  <pre>{{userInfo}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: first of all thanks a lot, can you explain what did in ng-option

Comment: well, `x for (x, y) in countriesToCities` basically makes the key value pairs for the country-city list and x selects the values i.e the cities, I modified it to bind the key to the `$scope.user.country` model by selecting `country as country..`